# Image to text converter

Tags: gratis, images, math, ocr

I have this book full of mathematical equations. I want a way to take the image of parts of the book, and convert it into a Word document with the mathematical equations in them. Now, if such a software hasn't been developed to handle mathematical equations in Word, then it should at least embed the mathematical equations as pictures in the Word document.

Does such *free* software exist? Ideally for Windows, but I will consider Linux as well (no Mac please).

Comment: Yes, but it is truely aweful.  Tessact https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/  and gocr  http://jocr.sourceforge.net/    After using these products you will **beg** Nuance to take your money to stop the pain.

Comment: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/top-5-free-ocr-software-tools-to-convert-your-images-into-text-nb/   You can try these, but when I used them in the past, I ran back to Omnipage as fast as I could.

Answer (score 4):

There is a whole field of software called OCR  or optical character recognition.  Omnipage regular or Pro from nuance has always worked well for me.  It can usually handle anything I throw at it.  If recognition is poor use a higher DPI in scanning, I usually use 600, but on tiny fonts I use 1200dpi.

Omnipage cost money, but you get what you pay for.

Over the years I have tried many other packages and found them lacking.  I am sure they have been improved over the years, so they could be better now.

Comment: I am sorry, but I forgot to add, I am looking for free software...

Comment: code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr     It is free, but it will be temperamental.  Good luck trying to train it on different fonts, I could never figure it out, or it was so painful I block the experience from my memory.

Answer (score 0):

OCR software can do that for you. You can search for ocr software on google play. Here I want to recommend Docs Matter to you. I only used Docs Matter before to help me manage my paper document.

Its main feature is to scan the document or images you have, and use the built-in OCR engine to retrieve text from document after scanning. You can modify and save recognition results after the OCR engine finished its work.

The average time for recognition of a document less than 6 seconds. The recognition accuracy can reach 99%. It can convert documents into PDF, Word, Text format files.

I think you can have a try. You can search Docs Matter on Google Play.